# Prove the additivity of the Renyi entropy: $H_{\beta}(p \times r) = H_{\beta}(p) + H_{\beta}(r)$

Tags: information-theory, entropy, probability, renyi-entropies

The Renyi entropy of order $\beta$, for a discrete probability distribution $p$ is given by
\begin{equation}
H_{\beta}(p) = \frac{1}{1 - \beta} ~\log \left( \sum_{i \in S} p(i)^{\beta} \right),
\end{equation}
where $S$ is the set of all strings in the support of $p$.

As is mentioned [here](https://perimeterinstitute.ca/personal/tfritz/2015/entropy.pdf), for two discrete distributions $p$ and $r$ the Renyi entropy of the product distribution $p \times r$ is

\begin{equation}
H_{\beta}(p \times r) = H_{\beta}(p) + H_{\beta}(r).
\end{equation}

What might be a proof of this fact?

Comment: what applications does Renyi entropy have in quantum

Comment: A quantum variant of the classical Renyi entropy appear in a lot of places in quantum information theory. Properties of the same can be found here: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Quantum_entropies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This only holds if the two distributions are independent. In this case
$$
\begin{aligned}
H_{\beta}(p \times q) &= \frac{1}{1-\beta} \log\left( \sum_{i,j}(p(i) q(j))^{\beta} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{1-\beta} \log\left( \left(\sum_{i}p(i)^{\beta}\right) \left(\sum_jq(j)^{\beta}\right) \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{1-\beta} \left(\log \left(\sum_{i}p(i)^{\beta}\right) + \log \left(\sum_{j}q(j)^{\beta}\right)\right) \\
&= H_{\beta}(p) + H_{\beta}(q) .
\end{aligned}
$$